# Encoding JSON body properly in Swift for HTTP Request

Tags: json, swift, httprequest

I am trying to encode key/value pairs in JSON for an HTTP request in Swift on iOS 15, but everything I try to put in the body shows up as the key when I post it.

The code:

```swift
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

let body = [
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456"
]

let bodyData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
    withJSONObject: body, options: []
)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = bodyData
```

When I post this to the server, the server receives:

```json
{
  "{\"email\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"123456\"}": ""
}
```

Am a Swift beginner, many thanks for any responses to this...

Comment: What does the server expect?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the request

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

That is what solved it for me when I had the same problem. This tells the server to parse the json as json instead of

{ jsonBody : "" }

which is what it seems to be doing right now.